# CUDA out of memory even though there is free memory when using the simple-transformers pytorch library

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model

Ive been trying to follow this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-transformers-introducing-the-easiest-bert-roberta-xlnet-and-xlm-library-58bf8c59b2a3) for the simple transformers library but I keep running into cuda errors that I dont quite understand.

`RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 6.00 GiB total capacity; 697.82 MiB already allocated; 3.99 GiB free; 744.00 MiB reserved in total by PyTorch)`

I dont understand why its failing to allocate memory when it says there is 4GB free. Im also seeing this error in the stack trace

`OSERROR: [WinError 1455] The paging file is too small for this operation to complete`

occasionally this one will also pop up.

`OSERROR: [WinError 1114] A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed`

Dont really know where to go from here.